# Understanding probabilistic inference graphs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, inference, graphical-model, generative-models

I am having trouble understanding inference graphs. In the diagram below I understand the graph on the left (forward graph) where the arrows describe the direction that data flows when training for example.

How should I understand the arrows on the inference graph to the right? Are they just the direction in which back-propagation is occurring?

[image]

*[Image reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06432.pdf)*

Anyone?